# Best output activation function for binary mask classification

Tags: machine-learning, keras, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

I have a CNN which inputs a satellite image and should output a mask where it finds cars. I have manually labelled images and created masks for each image where each pixel is 1 if there is part of a car in that pixel, 0 otherwise.

I am trying to work out the best output layer activation function and loss function, and I'm fishing for opinions. I know there is a wealth of information out there but I find myself getting confused about whether my problem is regression or classification.

Could someone please offer their opinion? I am currently using the following output and loss in keras:

```
conv10 = Conv2D(1, 1, activation='sigmoid')(conv9)

model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[conv10])

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-4), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Is this a good idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a good idea from my point of view, because you want to output a probability `P(px is part of a car | image)` for each pixel `px` in `image`. Therefore, that's a binary classification problem, for which using the `binary_crossentropy` loss function (plus a sigmoid activation in the output layer) is appropriate.

Comment: Ok thanks, it's nice to know I am going in the right direction